# Cellular Modules Weird Voltage 3.8V

Tags: voltage, cellphone, history

Does anyone know why cellular modules run at 3.8V instead of 5V or 3.3V? It seems weird that a different voltage was chosen to run them. I have seen some run at 1.8V and 2.8V. Thanks.

Edit: To make the question more clear. Why are cellular modules(used in M2M or cellphones to connect to cellular network) nominal voltage 3.8V instead of the more standard 3.3V or 5V?

Comment: Huh? What modules?

Comment: Most cellular modules need nominal voltage of 3.8V. Huawei MC509 and  Sierra Wireless wp series. These are just a 2 examples, but a lot of cellular modules run at 3.8V. There might not be an answer for why this voltage was chosen. I just think it would have been easier if a voltage like 5V or 3.3V would have been chosen.

Comment: From Huawei specifications: *Power Supply 3.2 V to 4.2 V (typical: 3.8 V)* This screams "internal buck to be fed directly from single rechargeable lithium cell".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can connect those modules directly to a lithium ion battery. They are specified for 3.2 V to 4.2 V (at least the Huawei MC50 is).

The nominal voltage of a single lithium cell is given between 3.6 V and 3.8 V depending on the exact chemistry. If it stops working below 3.2 V it even provides a form of battery protection as it doesn't drain the battery to dangerously low levels (dangerous for battery life, no explosions).

So you can save the power management circuitry. If you have a 3.3V power supply in your application, you can power the module with that as well.